# How can i resolve System.Object error when running app service in Azure?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have successfully deployed and can run my app service in Azure.
But i get the error:

```
 d:\home\site\wwwroot\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml(42): 
 The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. 
 You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0,
```

I have looked at the error logs , but there is nothing really informative that can help.
Where can i look to try and resolve this ?

```
   <Reference Include="System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b02f8f7f22d50a8a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

here is what is in packages

```
<package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
```

Comment: Could you please share your .csproj package references file.

Comment: what am i looking for as the .csproj contains some information i dont want to display , hope you understand

Comment: Just give the packages which you are referring.

Comment: if i copy C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\Facades\System.Runtime.dfll it seems to work, but why is the file not being deployed ?

Comment: Are you sure it is .dll or .dfll ?

Comment: just checked , it is  System.Runtime.dll

Comment: How does that file get deployed to Azure ?

Comment: In solution explorer, Right click,Unload the project .csproj file will be opened.Post the package references which are in that file.

Comment: i added it in the qquestion for formatting purposes

Comment: is there a mismatch ? if there is it  doesnt seem to be update on a restore

Comment: What is the .net framework version you are using ?

Comment: I have found that the System.runtime.dll was not set as copy local

Comment: Yes, If you do not set the dll as Copy local, tou will get this type of errors

Comment: if i set copy local , which file is updated , as when i try to commit to source control there is no file that is recognised as changed ?

Comment: Rebuild and deploy the application, check if you are still getting the error.

Comment: There must be an issue with the dll version you are using, what is the .net framework version ?

Comment: Are you able to see ***System.Runtime.dll*** in the bin folder ? If not add it in bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have tried to repro with the given packages in .csproj file, got the same issue.
  -In .csproj file
  Added below snippet

```cs
<Reference Include="System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b02f8f7f22d50a8a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
 <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
 <Private>True</Private>
 <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

I am getting the error,

-In .***csproj*** file , Add

```cs
  <Reference Include="System.Runtime"/>
```

- Delete the existing System.Runtime reference from bin folder.

[image]

- Add `System.Runtime` package in web.config file.

```cs
<compilation targetFramework="*.*" debug="true" > 
  <assemblies>
   <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /> 
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: so if i get this right, delete . Unload the we Project and add the above snippet frst. That is already present. Next under references in te web project , delete the System.Runtime reference and add it to the web.config section. At the moment I only have  assembly System.Windows.Forms.          Thing is why is it happening now ?

Comment: Also add   ***<Reference Include="System.Runtime"/>*** in .cs proj file

Comment: After doing the given setting, please let me know if you still face the issue ?

Comment: yep that is already there, let me try this now